# ER Diagram explained

Tags: database, attributes, erd

Can anybody explain the part with the multivalued attribute middleNames. How would that look in the database/tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The diagram isn't valid. Multivalued attributes don't have weak keys, otherwise they would be weak entities. Also, multivalued attributes don't need cardinality indicators, since they're supposed to be multivalued. Optionality can be indicated with a dashed line.

My preferred way of correcting the diagram would be to drop the `mnId` and `middleName` component attributes, like so:

[image: Multivalued attribute - conceptual]

Physically, this would be implemented as:

[image: Multivalued attribute - physical]

Note the composite primary key on the two columns of the MiddleNames table.